# Problema con listar un ArrayList en JAVA JSP

Tags: java, array, jsp

tengo el siguiente problema:

Estoy haciendo un carrito de compras, una tarea, soy novato en esto de Java Server Pages, y tengo una clase Producto donde tengo un metodo que devuelve un List e invoco a ese metodo desde un JSP llamado catalogo, vease aqui:

```
//Metodo
public List<Object> ver() {
    List<Object> p = new ArrayList<>();
    Connection con;
    Statement pred;
    ResultSet rst;
    String qry="SELECT * FROM productos";
    try {
        Class.forName(bd.getDriver());
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(bd.getUrl(), bd.getU(), bd.getP());
        pred = con.createStatement();
        rst = pred.executeQuery(qry);
//Contador para el indexado del array por cada objeto
        int cont = 0;
        while (rst.next()){
            p.add(cont,new producto( rst.getInt("ID_PRODUCTO"),
                                rst.getString("COD_COLOR"),
                                rst.getString("COD_SIZE"),
                                rst.getString("NOMBRE"),
                                rst.getDouble("PRECIO"),
                                rst.getString("IMAGEN")));
            cont++;
        }
        con.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return p;
}
```

Entonces tengo un JSP llamado catalogo como antes mencionaba que tiene el siguiente codigo:

```
producto prod = new producto();
List<Object> arrayprod = prod.ver();
int valor = arrayprod.size();
int id = (int) arrayprod.get(0);
String color = (String) arrayprod.get(1);
String size = (String) arrayprod.get(2);
String nombre = (String) arrayprod.get(3);
double precio = (double) arrayprod.get(4);
String imagen = (String) arrayprod.get(5);
int cont = 1;
%>
<section>
<%

    for (int i = 0;i<=valor;i++){
        while (i==6){
%>
        <div id="prod">
        <img src="<%=imagen%>">
        Nombre:<p><%=nombre%></p>
        Precio:<p><%=precio%></p>
        Color:<p><%=color%></p>
        Tamaño:<p><%=size%></p>
        <input type="button" name="send" value="<%=id%>" onclick="agregar()">
        </div>
<%
            i=0;
            cont++;
        }
        if (cont==3){
%>
            <br>
<%
            cont=1;
        }
    }
%>
</section>
```

El problema esta que cuando se ejecuta el JSP me lanza el siguiente error:

HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message An exception occurred processing JSP page [/catalogo.jsp] at line [16]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page [/catalogo.jsp] at line [16]

```
//Esto no es parte del error
13:     producto prod = new producto();
14:     List<Object> arrayprod = prod.ver();
15:     int valor = arrayprod.size();
16:     int id = (int) arrayprod.get(0);
17:     String color = (String) arrayprod.get(1);
18:     String size = (String) arrayprod.get(2);
19:     String nombre = (String) arrayprod.get(3);
```

Dice pues que en la linea 16 de mi codigo hay algo que esta mal, y me fijo  en el Root Case que lanza el error esta la siguiente linea:

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out-of-bounds for length 0

Dice que el index esta fuera del limite de la longitud 0(no logro interpretarlo bien).

Nota: Esta conectado a la base de datos la base de datos contiene datos.

Entonces aca no se que estaria o no funcionando, si es mi logica que esta mal o que, si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradeceria mucho.

Comment: ¿Depuraste el código del método `ver()`, para comprobar que si carga datos de la base de datos?

Comment: Empieza desde 1 el indice por eso te indica que esta fuera del limite

Comment: Entiendo que un Array siempre inicia con un indice 0 no? por eso pido con el metodo .get(0) el primer objeto guardado en el Array.
@LeoT

Comment: Si @E.Betanzos Trae los datos de la base de datos, lo que no hace y no se por que es no introducir en el Array los datos que devuelve el metodo.

Comment: ¿Los datos que devuelve qué método? Si te paras en la línea del `return` del método `ver()`, cuando estás depurando, ¿la lista `p` cuántos elementos tiene?

Comment: El metodo ver() de tipo List retorna un List con los datos que almacena en el objeto de tipo producto que es almacenado en la variable del array p, esos son los datos que ese metodo retorna, respondiendo a tu pregunta, y tiene 6 elementos.

Comment: da la impresion de que tiene 0 elementos. De lo contrario no veo donde esta el error.

Answer (score 1):

el erro parce estar cuando insertas en el arreglo

```
     p.add(cont,new producto( rst.getInt("ID_PRODUCTO")
```

cuando insertas y pasas el indice, tienes que asegurarte que el indice sea menor al tamaño del Arraylist, como no has insertado nada el tamaño es cero.
Para agregar elementos simplemente al final del array simplemente llama add sin el indice

```
     p.add(new producto( rst.getInt("ID_PRODUCTO")
```

por otra parte te recomiendo que cambies la forma como estas mapeando la información, en vez de hacer una lista crea un objeto con las propiedades que necesitas. Ejemplo:

```
class Producto{
      private int id;
      private String color;
      ...
      //aqui colocas las demas propiedades y su gettter and setter
}
```

y llamar los setter para llenar los datos y los getter para leerlos

```
   Producto p = new Producto();
   while (rst.next()){
        p.setId( rst.getInt("ID_PRODUCTO"));
        p.setColor( rst.getString("COD_COLOR"));
    }
```

Comment: Antes no le tenia un indexador, bueno, tampoco habia hecho lo de los getters y setters con la clase, aunque tengo la clase asi como pones mas arriba, lo intentare de esa manera, gracias por la respuesta.